# How can I tell if a JodaTime time zone was explicitly set?

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, timezone, jodatime

Encoding time zone info in a `DateTime` object is straightforward:

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatterWithZone = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm ZZZ").withOffsetParsed();
final DateTimeFormatter formatterWithoutZone = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm");

final DateTime dateTimeExplicitZone = formatterWithZone.parseDateTime("April 26, 2016, 11:11 PST8PDT");
final DateTime dateTimeImplicitZone = formatterWithoutZone.parseDateTime("April 26, 2016, 11:11");

System.out.println(dateTimeExplicitZone);
System.out.println(dateTimeExplicitZone.getZone());

System.out.println(dateTimeImplicitZone);
System.out.println(dateTimeImplicitZone.getZone());

// 2016-04-26T11:11:00.000-07:00
// PST8PDT
// 2016-04-26T11:11:00.000-04:00
// America/New_York
```

However, I would like to be able to tell if the time zone was parsed explicitly farther downstream.

For example, if the parsing occurred without a time zone, I want to take specific actions to ensure that the time zone is set manually by some other means.

My workaround has been to create two parsers:  one for format strings with time zones and one for strings without, but this is somewhat inelegant.

Is there a way to tell using the JodaTime API if the time zone was explicitly set by parsing or by method call, versus inferred from the JVM local time?